# Data is not going through the ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using Facebook login feature & transferring some variables to other page through ajax. This particular ajax code isn't working, data is not going through. However I've other ajax code in other pages that works pretty good.

I'm not able to find the defect in the code.

Here is the code:

**Page where ajax is called**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXX',
        status     : false,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });
}

function Login()
{
    FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) 
    {
        getUserInfo();
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
    },{scope:'email,public_profile'});
}

function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
        var permission_response = JSON.stringify(response);
        var permissions = eval('('+permission_response+')');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_save_facebook_data.php",
            data: {permissions:permissions},
            success: function(option){
                alert(option); // Nothing coming here, blank alert
            }
        });

    });
}
```

**AJAX Page**

```
$permissions=$_POST['permissions'];
echo $permissions;
```

Anybody can help in this? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: did you try to debug

Comment: Yup, data is coming for this variable/s. 'console.log' is okay.

Answer (score 0):

FB.api is asynchrone function, so your var permissions doesn't exist when you do your ajax call.

Try:

```
function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
        var permission_response = JSON.stringify(response);
        var permissions = eval('('+permission_response+')'); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_save_facebook_data.php",
            data: {permissions:permissions},
            success: function(option){
                alert(option); // Nothing coming here, blank alert
            }
        });       
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is indeed my code, I made a mistake while editing in a question. This doesn't work though.

Comment: did you try to debug? console.log(permissions); before ajax call

Comment: Yup, data is coming for this variable/s. console.log is okay.

Comment: in your ajax page just  write var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Ok! let's continue: data: {permissions: permission_response},

Comment: Again, blank alert, no data.